# Taylor expansion of retarded vector potential

Tags: electromagnetism, potential

I am currently trying to understand the Taylor expansion in radiation zone of the vector potential for a general time dependence. I know that the retarded potential is given by:

$$\textbf{A}(\textbf{r},t) = \frac{\mu_0}{4\pi}\int\frac{\textbf{J}({\textbf{r}'}, t_r)}{R}\,\mathrm dV',$$

where $t_r = t - R/c$ and $R = |\textbf{r}-\textbf{r}'|$. Since we are in radiation zone we can approximate $R \approx r$ and then Taylor expand the current density around $t' = t - r/c$. By just including the first two terms of the current density we get:

$$\textbf{A}(\textbf{r},t) = \frac{\mu_0}{4\pi r}\int\textbf{J}({\textbf{r}'}, t') + \dot{\textbf{J}}({\textbf{r}'}, t')\frac{\textbf{r}'\cdot \hat{\textbf{r}}}{c}\,\mathrm dV',$$

where the dot over $\textbf{J}$ represents the derivative with respect to $t'$. I have seen multiple documents where after this step, they write the integral as following:

$$\textbf{A}(\textbf{r},t) = \frac{\mu_0}{4\pi r}\int\textbf{J}({\textbf{r}'}, t')\,\mathrm dV' + \frac{\mu_0}{4\pi r} \frac{\partial}{\partial t'}\int\textbf{J}({\textbf{r}'}, t')\frac{\textbf{r}'\cdot \hat{\textbf{r}}}{c}\,\mathrm dV'.$$

My question is: How one can put the partial derivative outside the integral? In further calculations, one uses that $\textbf{r}'$ is dependent on $t'$ so should it not be any kind of product rule when one is putting the derivative outside the integral?

Answer (score 1):

Note that $t'$ is not the retarded time corresponding to the position $\mathbf r'$.  Instead, $t'$ is the retarded time corresponding to the position $\mathbf r$: $\ t' = t - r/c \ $. So, $t'$ as defined here is independent of $\mathbf {r}'$.

$\large \int \mathbf {\dot J}(\mathbf r', t') \frac{\mathbf r' \cdot \hat {\mathbf {r}} }{c}dV' = \int\left[\lim \limits_{h\to 0} \frac{\mathbf J(\mathbf r', t'+h)-\mathbf J(\mathbf r', t')}{h} \right] \frac{\mathbf r' \cdot \hat {\mathbf {r}} }{c} dV' = $

$\large \lim \limits_{h\to 0} \frac{ \int \mathbf J(\mathbf r', t'+h)\frac{\mathbf r' \cdot \hat {\mathbf {r}} }{c}dV' -\int \mathbf J(\mathbf r', t')\frac{\mathbf r' \cdot \hat {\mathbf {r}} }{c}dV'   }{h}=  $

$\large \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \left[\int \mathbf J(\mathbf r', t)\frac{\mathbf r' \cdot \hat {\mathbf {r}} }{c}dV'  \right]_{t=t'} \equiv \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \int \mathbf J(\mathbf r', t')\frac{\mathbf r' \cdot \hat {\mathbf {r}} }{c}dV'$

Comment: I have seen that in further calculations one use that r' is dependent on t' to show that the integrals correspond to electric dipole moment, magnetic dipole moment and quadrupole moment. Is this because of r' has an implicit dependency on t'?